# sas sql : filter out corrupted row

Tags: sql, sas

I need to copy data from own table to another and filter out corrupted rows; 
I have a column with dates and sometimes I have rows like this "    . " - random number of spaces and one dot. 
how can I make my sql to ignore these rows?

i tried to make using

```
where (trim(put(DatesOfRun) not like '.'
```

and multiple other variance of

> "where not like"

or

> "where <>"

but all of them gave me an errors like

> "Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different
>   data types."

or

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following:

and a long list of operators

Comment: is your row text or numeric?  select date from file were date is not missing

Comment: i expected it to be numeric but this dot character is just a way how sas shows an empty cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to confirm if this is a *character* or a *numeric* field.  `.` is how SAS displays `null` (`missing` in SAS speak) for numerics, so it's entirely possible you have a numeric field.

```
where not missing(DatesOfRun)
```

or

```
where DatesOfRun is not null
```

Either of those should do it, if it's numeric.

If it is character, then it's fairly simple.

```
where not (strip(DatesOfRun) = '.')
```

`trim` only trims blanks at the end, `strip` removes from both sides.

It's also possible you have non-breaking spaces or other things that are going to mess the latter up; if the `strip` one works as in doesn't error, but doesn't actually remove the characters, you may want to use a data step and `put` that variable to the log using `$HEX32.` format (with appropriate width, 2 times the number of characters possible), and see what comes out; if you don't recognize the characters or don't know how to handle ASCII codes, come back here and ask a new question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you are trying to ignore results where the DatesOfRun column contains the character '.'? If so, you may want to use wildcard operators if the '.' can appear in random locations, such as '.%' or '%.%'

Also, check the datattype of the DatesOfRun column; this could influence results as well.

Two WHERE clauses could potentially solve your issue; try using this WHERE clause and see if it throws an error:

```
    WHERE DatesOfRun is not null
    AND DatesOfRun not like '%.%'
```

Comment: I tried it before and got an error "Expression using equals (^=) has components that are of different data types."

Comment: Then DATESOFRUN is not a character variable and does not contain "." at all. Instead the value is just missing and when SAS prints it for you it is using the period to let you know that the value was missing.

Comment: `not like '%.%'` will match any string containing a period/decimal (even with other nonspace characters). This may or may not be intended, and is certainly dangerous.

Comment: Well if DatesOfRun is a date column then I would hope it's formatted in a manner that wouldn't contain decimals. The question clearly stated that the rows needing to be ignored started with a '.', so I suppose '.%' would work as well, but this covers all bases assuming the DatesOfRun column is never supposed to contain a decimal.